# Ways to voltage shift a wave down to ground

Tags: voltage, transformer, wave

Say I have a wave signal that is always above ground, that is, the signal is positively clamped to the ground.

(EDIT: from an input of a helpful user, I now know this should be called "negatively clamped", my mistake)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flVKmn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How do I voltages shift this to ground? I mean, have the average of a single period of the original wave exactly at ground; the upper half of the original at positive; and the original lower half at negative voltage.

Assuming we only work with sinusoidal waves, I believe this can be done using a transformer and capacitor and the upper half of the original wave, but what are my other options?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzsDkd.png)</sup>

-- I don't know how to chop off the other half of the sine wave from V_IN

EDIT:

In the 2nd circuit, when I mentioned only taking the upper half of the sine wave, I mean that's just the minimal input we need. I suppose we can simply leave out the capacitor and take the whole wave. Though I've never been sure of creating reverse direction currents (on the 2nd winding) if the input (1st winding) happens to be simply oscillating, but negatively clamped to ground.

EDIT:

Here's what we're trying to do:
[image]

to:

[image]

In other words we are trying to remove the DC component which happens to be the average of a period.

Another way of saying it is using a differential amplifier of gain of 1.

Comment: What is this signal? Audio, RF, a mains voltage? 100 mV, 10 V, 400 kV? i.e., Describe the problem properly and add a schematic if it will clarify thing. **Edit your question** rather than post comments.

Comment: RF range, about 12V....

Comment: If the signal is positively clamped to ground then it only extends in the negative and therefore CANNOT be above ground.

Comment: Alright... "negatively clamped"...

Comment: Is the sinewave clamped in such a way that any amplitude changes (modulation) only results in amplitude changes to the top of the waveform and, if so, should that asymmetry be carried thru to the desired output waveform?

Comment: What is *"positively (EDIT: negatively) clamped to the ground"* supposed to mean?

Comment: @Andyaka: Yes, amplitude modulation only stretches upward (magnitude). No, the asymmetry should not be carried. the average of the sine wave of a period should be clamped to 0V. –

Comment: Why don't you try simulating with a high pass filter. LTSpice is free.

Comment: How can you think of frequency when we're talking about amplitude? Stop misleading the discussion.

Comment: Hint - What's the frequency of a DC offset? Which, since you are evidently short on clues, is the common name of the thing you are trying to get rid of, unless you are managing to fail to communicate your actual problem even more than is thus far apparent; which seems quite possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a transformer (which, being far from ideal, do terrible things to most signals.) This is what a capacitor coupled input does - removes any DC bias on an AC signal. [and it couples to the whole input signal, not "the upper half"]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8nNfF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Source is a 10V sine with a 5 v offset (ie, all above ground) out is centered on 0V. Feel free to alter the wave shape if it makes you happier, makes no difference.

Comment: OK, pretty good... I had to increase the pull down resistor to 10M ohms, just to get rid of the lag at the output... Don't really understand how it works, though. Seem to work for any frequency and wide range of voltage input... Might just go with this.

Comment: Correction... The increase to 10M ohms seems to be only needed for very low frequencies, for MHz and above 100k ohms works very well...

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a *high pass filter*.  The simplest form of such a filter is a capacitor in series followed by a resistor to ground.

The real trick is deciding what is signal and what is average level.  If this is audio, for example, then the real signal goes down to 20 Hz.  You would therefore want the high pass filter to rolloff somewhat below that, like 10 Hz.  A 10 µF cap and 1.6 kΩ resistor would do that, for example.

The reason there is a tradeoff to make here is because the lower you make the high pass filter rollof frequency, the slower it will respond to the average level.  The 10 Hz filter above has a time constant of 16 ms.  This will settle 95% to a new average level in 3 time constants, or 48 ms.  If you care about 99% settling, then you have to wait 4.6 time constants or 74 ms.

It is possible to get a faster average level response time for the same minimum passband frequency by using a more complicated filter, but there are limits to this too.

Comment: This is not strictly Frequency Modulation, I'm putting together a general purpose RF amplifier at GHz range. Also, it should be able to work with pulses. From all that we are talking about now is amplitudes (non-invertingly amplifying a signal).